# Probability of dice and coin throwing experiment

Tags: probability, contest-math

Consider the experiment of throwing a die, if a multiple of 3 comes up, throw the
die again and if any other number comes, toss a coin. Find the conditional probability of the event **‘the coin shows a tail’**, given that *‘at least one throw of die shows a 3’*.

I don't know how to deal with this kind of problem. Moreover, there are three answers I am encountering. The first answer is zero, which I intuitively feel wrong, the second answer is $\frac{1}{10}$ and third is $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: What happens when you throw the die again? Is that it, or do you then apply the same rules again (if a multiple of $3$ comes up, you throw it yet again, otherwise you toss a coin)?

Comment: I think we have to apply the same rule again. I have reproduced the problem verbatim.

Comment: Then it's a badly posed problem; no wonder people are giving different answers to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is given that at least one throw of the die shows a three. As a result, there would be a coin toss involved. The probability of getting a tail in that coin toss would be $\frac12$, which is also the required conditional probability and answer.

Comment: Why does the existence of a throw of three lead to a coin toss being involved? In the problem statement, a coin is tossed when anything other than a multiple of $3$ was rolled.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, the problem statement is unclear.

One possible interpretation is that when the die is rerolled, the same rules apply again, i.e. it is yet again rerolled if a multiple of three comes up, and a coin is tossed otherwise. Under this interpretation, there is exactly one coin toss at the end of the process, irrespective of how many multiples of three were rolled in between, so the probability that the coin shows tails is $\frac12$ (assuming the coin is fair).

Another possible interpretation is that the rules only apply to the first roll of the die, and if it is rerolled, that’s it. Under this interpretation, given that at least one $3$ was rolled, there is no coin toss, and (assuming that the coin isn’t just lying around showing tails without having been tossed) the probability that the coin shows tails is $0$.

I don’t see any interpretation that would lead to the answer $\frac1{10}$.